# How to solve Unicoder problem when reading csv

Tags: python, csv

I am totally new to python. I am using a package that takes medical text and annotates it with classifiers called [pyConTextNLP](https://github.com/chapmanbe/pyConTextNLP/blob/master/notebooks/BasicSentenceMarkup.ipynb)

It basically takes some natural language text, adds some 'modifiers' to it and classifies it whilst removing negative findings.

The problem I am having is how to add the list of modifiers as a csv or a yaml file. I have been following the basic setup instructions [here](https://github.com/chapmanbe/pyConTextNLP/blob/master/notebooks/BasicSentenceMarkup.ipynb):

The problem is the line here:

```
modifiers = itemData.get_items("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chapmanbe/pyConTextNLP/master/KB/lexical_kb_05042016.yml")
```

`itemData.get_items` doesn't look like it exists anymore and there is a function instead called `itemData.get_fileobj()`. This takes a csv file as far as I understand and the csv is passed to the function `markup.markItems(modifiers, mode="modifier")` which looks at the text and 'marks up' any concepts in the raw text that match the modifiers.

The error that I get when trying to run the example code is:

```
if not `item.getLiteral() in compiledRegExprs:`
```

and this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'UnicodeReader' object has no attribute 'getLiteral'
```

The whole code is [here](https://github.com/chapmanbe/pyConTextNLP/blob/master/notebooks/BasicSentenceMarkup.ipynb): but I have also written it below

```
import networkx as nx
import pyConTextNLP.itemData as itemData
import pyConTextNLP.pyConTextGraph as pyConText


reports = [
    """IMPRESSION: Evaluation limited by lack of IV contrast; however, no evidence of
      bowel obstruction or mass identified within the abdomen or pelvis. Non-specific interstitial opacities and bronchiectasis seen at the right
     base, suggestive of post-inflammatory changes.""",
    """DIAGNOSIS: NO SIGNIFICANT PATHOLOGY

MICRO  These biopsies of large bowel mucosa show oedema of the lamina propriabut no architectural abnormality
There is no dysplasia or malignancy
There is no evidence of active inflammation
There is no increase in the inflammatory cell content of the lamina propria""" ,
    """IMPRESSION:
     1.  2.0 cm cyst of the right renal lower pole.  Otherwise, normal appearance
     of the right kidney with patent vasculature and no sonographic evidence of
     renal artery stenosis.
     2.  Surgically absent left kidney.""",
         """IMPRESSION: No definite pneumothorax""",
    """IMPRESSION:  New opacity at the left lower lobe consistent with pneumonia."""
]

modifiers = itemData.get_fileobj("/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyConTextNLP-0.6.2.0-py3.7.egg/pyConTextNLP/CSV_Modifiers.csv")
targets = itemData.get_fileobj("/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyConTextNLP-0.6.2.0-py3.7.egg/pyConTextNLP/CSV_targets.csv")



def markup_sentence(s, modifiers, targets, prune_inactive=True):
    """
    """
    markup = pyConText.ConTextMarkup()
    markup.setRawText(s)
    markup.cleanText()
    markup.markItems(modifiers, mode="modifier")
    markup.markItems(targets, mode="target")
    markup.pruneMarks()
    markup.dropMarks('Exclusion')
    # apply modifiers to any targets within the modifiers scope
    markup.applyModifiers()
    markup.pruneSelfModifyingRelationships()
    if prune_inactive:
        markup.dropInactiveModifiers()
    return markup

reports[3]


markup = pyConText.ConTextMarkup()


isinstance(markup,nx.DiGraph)

markup.setRawText(reports[4].lower())
print(markup)
print(len(markup.getRawText()))

markup.cleanText()
print(markup)
print(len(markup.getText()))

markup.markItems(modifiers, mode="modifier")
print(markup.nodes(data=True))
print(type(list(markup.nodes())[0]))

markup.markItems(targets, mode="target")

for node in markup.nodes(data=True):
    print(node)

    markup.pruneMarks()
for node in markup.nodes(data=True):
    print(node)

    print(markup.edges())

    markup.applyModifiers()
for edge in markup.edges():
    print(edge)
```

`markItems` function is here:

```
def markItems(self, items, mode="target"):
    """tags the sentence for a list of items
    items: a list of contextItems"""
    if not items:
        return
    for item in items:
        self.add_nodes_from(self.markItem(item, ConTextMode=mode), 
         category=mode)
```

The question is, how can I get the code to read the list in the csv file without throwing this error?

Comment: Can you use the Pandas package and then use pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')

Comment: Your first two links are broken,

Comment: @Anthon. Thanks. Should be fixed now